# How to get text from link (Python/Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have read a lot of answers to similar question but nothing works for me.

I want retrived font's name from link as a text:

```
<a href="/fonts/stephen-rapp/solantra/" class="fcFontName">Solantra</a>
```

**Below is code for my basic spider:**

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from myfontsitem.items import MyfontsitemItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "fontspider"
    start_urls = ['https://myfonts.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="fcTitle"]')

        for question in questions:
            item = MyfontsitemItem
            item['fontname'] = question.xpath('//a[@class="fcFontName"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

**This how looks my items.py:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyfontsitemItem(scrapy.Item):
    fontname = scrapy.Field()
```

And this is result for my xpath in Chrome console - it display exactly amount of these elements on page, but only as a word "text" not font's name:
View from console:

[image]

But I only I can see is empty json:

```
scrapy crawl fontspider -o test.json
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to instanciate the `MyfontsitemItem`class:

```
            item = MyfontsitemItem()
            item['fontname'] = question.xpath('//a[@class="fcFontName"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Also, the `fcTitle` and `fcFontName` aren't present on the initial HTML code. The seems to be generated later with javascript, so they can't be fetch with scrapy.

You will need to look for another information or use some javascript rendering proxy like [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use scrapy-splash